# Transform positions from networkx graph to dash cytoscape space

Tags: python, networkx, plotly-dash, cytoscape

I would like to create a dash Cytoscape graph based on an adjacency matrix. For that I implemented the steps [proposed by this user on the plotly forum](https://community.plotly.com/t/converting-networkx-graph-object-into-cytoscape-format/23224/2) to produce a list of elements that can be interpreted by `dash_cytoscape.Cytoscape`. Everything 'works fine' and I can reproduce the graph, only the positions seem to be on the wrong scale. In `networkx` they seem to be on a range from -1 to 1 whereas Dash/Cytoscape uses a different coordinate system. How could I transform the positions?

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

# create an adjancy matrix
A = np.array([[0,1,2,3],
              [1,0,1,0],
              [2,1,0,0],
              [3,0,0,0]],
             dtype=float)

# we can plot the adjancy matrix as a graph using networkx (we would like to see this exact same graph when we start the dash app)
G = nx.DiGraph(A)
nx.draw(G,with_labels=True)
```

[image]

```
def from_A_to_cy(A):
    '''Create a lists of elements that can be interpreted by dash_cytoscape.Cytoscape'''
    
    # 1.) create graph object
    G = nx.DiGraph(A)
    
    # 2 ) get node pos
    pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
    
    # 3.) get cytoscape layout
    cy = nx.readwrite.json_graph.cytoscape_data(G)
    
    # 4.) Add the dictionary key label to the nodes list of cy
    for n in cy['elements']['nodes']:
         for k,v in n.items():
             v['label'] = v.pop('value')
    
    # 5.) Add the pos you got from (2) as a value for data in the nodes portion of cy
    for n,p in zip(cy['elements']['nodes'],pos.values()):
        n['pos'] = {'x':p[0],'y':p[1]}
    
    # 6.) Take the results of (3)-(5) and write them to a list, like elements_ls
    elements_ls = cy['elements']['nodes'] + cy['elements']['edges']
    
    return elements_ls

# run dash and take in the list of elements
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape-two-nodes',
        layout={'name':'preset'},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '400px'},
        elements=from_A_to_cy(A)
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```